# .append() an element, click() not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to add an element to the DOM, and then working with this element, once clicked. However, I don't think the function below registers because this is a self invoking function (located at the end of the HTML), and is run only at the beginning.

```
 (function (){
    $('body').append('<span class="test">test</span>');
})

 $('.test').click(function(){
     console.log(this);
 });

})();
```

the click event handler is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're element is dynamically appended you can use `on()` or chain the `click()` event.

```
//Using on()

$('body').on('click', '.test', function(){
    // Bla
});


//Chaining click()

$('<span class="test">test</span>').click(function(){
    // Bla
}).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can do this,

```
$(function() {
    $('body').append('<span class="test">test</span>');
    $('.test').click(function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

though `live` or `on` would be the better alternative if you don't know in advance when that element is going to get added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Change this -

```
$('.test').click(function()
{
    console.log(this);
});
```

to this -

```
$('.test').live('click', function()
{
    console.log(this);
});
```

[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation.

**EDIT**

As of jquery 1.7, `live` has been deprecated. Use `on` instead -

```
$('body').on('click', '.test', function()
{
    console.log(this);
});
```

[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfRhq/1/) demo.

Remember, if you want to bind event handlers to dynamically generated DOM elements then you need to use either `live`(deprecated) or `on`.

Comment: Your demo only works because you're appending the `.test` element before registering the click handler. Try moving the append to after the handler - it won't work. If you want the handler to truly be live, you need to bind the event to a higher element and pass it a context. See elclanrs' answer.

Comment: @ChristianVarga: Yup, you are right. Thanks for pointing this out, I'll edit my answer right away!

Answer (score 0):

In your example code you are the closing the wrapper function after the span is added to the body, if you remove the `})` line, your code should work just fine:

```
(function (){
  $('body').append('<span class="test">test</span>');
  // }) <- remove this line

  $('.test').click(function(){
    console.log(this);
  });
})();
```

As other people have already answered with, you can chain in jQuery so you would be able to do any of these to get the same result:

```
function someFunction() {
  console.log(this);
}

// work from the span and attach a direct handler
$('<span class="test">test</span>').on('click', someFunction).appendTo('body');

// work from the body attaching direct handlers
$('body')
  .append('<span class="test">test</span>')
  .find('.test')
  .on('click', someFunction);

// work from the body attaching a delegate handler
$('body')
  .append('<span class="test">test</span>')
  .on('click', '.test', someFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were closing the function just after the append part thats why click handler wasn't working

```
$(function() {
    $('body').append('<span class="test">test</span>');
    $('.test').click(function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
})();
```